# android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE intent handling (in Activity)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

I would like to received a notification of the change of state of WiFi connection in my Android application.
I found several suggestion (here on SO) that mostly leads to the definition of an intent.
I'm using this approach:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    checkWiFi();
}

public BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null)
            checkWiFi();
    }
};
```

That works but I'm wondering if I can use a Manifest centric approach i.e. if I put this in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I should be notified of the incoming intent . Right?
How can I handle this in my Activity?

Best regards, Mike

Answer (score 0):

You should create class
`MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`

and next Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: In other words I cannot handle the intent by the `Activity` itself. I tried the approach you are suggesting but I don't understand how to notify the event from the receiver to the `Activity` (besides using a `LocalBroadcastManager` and `Intents` but this sounds a little redundant) .